# este codigo si funciona, pero en versiones antiguas

Tags: nodejs, npm, paquetes-npm

este codigo tiene formidable@2, tarde en darme cuenta que era una version antigua, deseo que este codigo funcione con la version actual Julio 2023

`const formidable = require('formidable')`

recien estoy estudiando nodejs y llegue a esta perte dificil para mi
[parte dificil de este pequeño curso](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/nodejsya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=14&codigo=14&inicio=0)

```
function subir(pedido, respuesta) {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
  form.parse(pedido, function (err, fields, files) {
    let path = files.foto1.filepath
    let nuevoPath = './public/upload/' + files.foto1.originalFilename
    fs.rename(path, nuevoPath, function (error) {
      respuesta.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
      respuesta.write('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>' +
        'Archivo subido<br><a href="index.html">Retornar</a></body></html>')
      respuesta.end()
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui tienes una 'traduccion' de tu código que sirve para la ultima version, específicamente la version 3:

```
const { formidable } = require('formidable')

function subir(pedido, respuesta) {
  const form = formidable({})
  try {
    form.parse(pedido, (err, _, files) => {
      if(err) throw new Error(`Error al parsear el form: ${err}`)
      let path = files.foto1[0].filepath
      let nuevoPath = './public/upload/' + files.foto1[0].originalFilename
      fs.rename(path, nuevoPath, function (error) {
        if(error) throw new Error(`Error al escribir el archivo en el servidor: ${err}`)
        respuesta.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        respuesta.write('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body>' +
          'Archivo subido<br><a href="index.html">Retornar</a></body></html>')
        respuesta.end()  
      })
    })
  } catch(err) {
    respuesta.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
    respuesta.end(`error interno (subir): ${err}`)
  } 
}
```

Es un poco mas largo porque estoy capturando los errores y enviando respuestas personalizadas, pero ya le hice tests y funciona bien, basta leer la documentacion de [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)